# Dynamically framing column names to pass it for select while creating Spark Data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm working in Spark and Scala for the past 2 months and I'm new to this technology. I framed the select columns(with regexp_replace) as List [String] () and passed for Spark Data frame creation and its throwing me error as "Cannot resolve". Please find below the steps, I have followed and tried.

Defining the val:

```
Defining the column which I would like to identify in the src data frame
val col_name = "region_id"
Defining the column which will be used to replace the src data frame column from ref data frame
val surr_key_col_name = "surrogate_key"
```

I have created two Data frames as shown below

**src_df**

```
region id | region_name | region_code  
10001189  | Spain       |    SP09 8545  
10001765  | Africa      |    AF97 6754
```

**ref_df**

```
region id | surrogate_key  
1189      |    2345  
1765      |    8978
```

---

```
val src_df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("s3://bucket/src_details.csv")
val ref_df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("s3://bucket/ref_details.csv")
```

I'm iterating through to identify the column I need to use reg match and replace with another Data Frame column value and storing it in List to pass it to Data Frames select

```
val src_header_rec = src_df.columns.toList

//Loop through source file header to identify the region_id and replace it with surrogate_id by doing a pattern match( I don't want to replace the 
for (src_header_cols <- src_header_rec) {
if (col_name == src_header_cols) {
src_column_names :+="regexp_replace("+"$"+s""""src.$src_header_cols""""+","+"$"+s""""ref.$src_header_cols""""+","+"$"+s""""ref.$surr_key_col_name""""+")"+".as("+s""""$src_header_cols""""+")"
}
else {
src_column_names :+= "src."+src_header_cols
}
}
```

After building the select column in the List [String] () using the for loop above, I'm passing it to the select columns for final_df creation

```
val final_df = src_df.alias("src").join(ref_df.alias("ref"), src_df(col_name)=== ref_df(col_name),"left_outer").select(src_column_names.head,src_column_names.tail:_*)
```

If I directly pass the columns without using the List [String] () in the select of the data frame my regexp_replace substitution works

```
val final_df = src_df.alias("src").join(ref_df.alias("ref"), src_df(col_name)=== ref_df(col_name),"left_outer").select(regexp_replace($"src.region_id",$"ref.region_id",$"ref.surrogate_key").as("region_id"))
```

I'm not sure why its not working when I'm passing it as a List [String] ()

When I remove the regexp_replace substitution in the for loop and pass it as List [String] () for Data Frame select it works properly as shown below:

This code works very well with Data Frame select:

```
for (src_header_cols <- src_header_rec) {
if (col_name == src_header_cols) {
src_column_names :+= "ref."+surr_key_col_name
}
else {
src_column_names :+= "src."+src_header_cols
}
}

val final_df = src_df.alias("src").join(ref_df.alias("ref"), src_df(col_name)===ref_df(col_name),"left_outer").select(src_column_names.head,src_column_names.tail:_*)
```

The result/output Data Frame I'm trying to derive is

**final_df**

```
region id    | region_name | region_code  
1000**2345** | Spain       |  SP09 8545  
1000**8978** | Africa      |  AF97 6754
```

So, when I'm trying to build the Spark Data Frame select in the for loop with regexp_replace as a List and use it its throwing me "Cannot resolve" error.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried creating Temporary view of the Data Frame and used the same regexp in the select statement of the Temporary view. It worked. Please find below the code I have tried and it worked.

```
//This for loop will scan through my header list and whichever column matches it frames regexp for those columns.So, the region_id from the Data Frame header matches the variable value that I have defined.
for (src_header_cols <- src_header_rec) {
    if (col_name == src_header_cols) {

        src_column_names :+= "regexp_replace(src."+s"$src_header_cols"+",ref."+s"$ref_col_name"+",ref."+s"$surr_key_col_name"+")"+s" $src_header_cols"
    }
    else {
        src_column_names :+= "src."+src_header_cols
    }
} 

//Creating Temporary view to apply SQL queries on it
src_df.createOrReplaceTempView("src")
ref_df.createOrReplaceTempView("ref")

//Framing SQL statements to be passed while querying
val selectExpr_1 = "select "+src_column_names.mkString(",")
val selectExpr_2 = selectExpr_1+" from src left outer join ref on(src."+s"$col_name"+" = ref."+s"$ref_col_name"+")"

// Creating a final Data Frame using the SQL statement created
val src_policy_masked_df = spark.sql(s"$selectExpr_2")
```